# Gensim resume training starting training from scratch

Tags: gensim

I am attempting to train an encoding for a text using gensim. I run the text over 5000 iterations (Document is ~250,000 words long, and Gensim is training over ~7500 frequent words), and the summed training loss for each iteration reduces from ~800,000 to 4,000 in that time. That said, when plotted, it is clear that training ended early and that further training would reduce the loss. However, when I load back in the saved model and run training:

```
model = Word2Vec.load("encodings")
model.train(lines, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter, compute_loss=True, callbacks=[logLoss, saveModel])
```

Training appears to start over from scratch with the initial training error ~800,000 and reduces back down to 4,000. I am saving the model with `model.save("encodings")`, and the saved model appears to be at least partially trained as word vector similarities seem somewhat reasonable. I want to further train my encoding, but this isn't working. (Note, initially training my encoding for more time ie. `iter=10000` doesn't improve my loss (it starts at 800,000 and ends at 4,000). Reducing the initial alpha or min_alpha over this extended period does not help either. Initial training is run with:

```
model = Word2Vec(lines, min_count=2, size=300, workers=8, sg=1, iter=5000, compute_loss=True, callbacks=[logLoss, saveModel])
```

Comment: Could it be that you are calling the original model object to specify the corpus instead of the trained model, encodings?  Did you ever figure out how to fix this?